# Change UITabBarItem badge font in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem, badge

I want change my tabbarItem badge font and I tried to do this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478417/swift-how-to-change-uitabbaritem-badge-font) but as it says in the comments it works for iOS 10 but there are issues in iOS 11. I'm trying to do this in iOS 12 using swift 4 but it doesn't work.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setBadgeTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont(name: "IRANSans-Bold", size: 14) as Any], for: .normal)
```

Please let me know if there is anyway to do this or I need to make a custom class for that.

Comment: Played with it for a small time, and it seems like it doesn't allow font modification on the tabbar item badge this way. Changing the tabbar font works, but not the badge font somehow...

Comment: @balazs630 thanks, so any library for custom badge?

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and found out that it is not possible to change tab bar item badge font. So I came out with writing an extension for UITabBarController as follow:

```
    func setCustomBadge(){
    removeMyCustomBadge(view: self.tabBar)
    setBadgeLabel(view: self.tabBar)
}
func setBadgeLabel(view:UIView){
    for subview in (view.subviews){
        let myType = String(describing: type(of: subview))
        print(myType)
        if myType == "_UIBadgeView" {
          let customBadeg : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: subview.frame.origin.x, y: subview.frame.origin.y, width: subview.frame.size.width, height: subview.frame.size.height))
            customBadeg.font = UIFont(name: "IRANSans", size: 10)
            customBadeg.layer.masksToBounds = true
            customBadeg.layer.cornerRadius = customBadeg.frame.size.height/2
            customBadeg.textAlignment = .center
            customBadeg.textColor = UIColor.white
            customBadeg.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Red")
            customBadeg.text = Utility().enNums2Fa(inputString: String(format: "%d", Utility().retrieveUserBasketBadge()))
            view.addSubview(customBadeg)
            subview.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            setBadgeLabel(view:subview)
        }
    }
  }
}
```